# Converting multiple word documents to multiple PDFs at the same time using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I found this code pertaining to the issue in the title on the following website.I need to convert multiple word docs to pdfs https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-batch-convert-word-documents-into-pdf-files/

I'm not sure if this is safe to use or will solve my problem and need some help from someone who can read code

```
    'Convert .doc or .docx to .pdf files via Send To menu
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For i= 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count -1
       docPath = WScript.Arguments(i)
       docPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(docPath)
       If LCase(Right(docPath, 4)) = ".doc" Or LCase(Right(docPath, 5)) = ".docx" Then
          Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
          pdfPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(docPath) & "\" & _
        fso.GetBaseName(docpath) & ".pdf"
          objWord.Visible = False
          Set objDoc = objWord.documents.open(docPath)
          objDoc.saveas pdfPath, 17
          objDoc.Close
          objWord.Quit   
       End If 
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tweaking version and tested on my machine on windows 10 (32 bits) and office 2007 :

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' This vbscript is inspired from here https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-batch-convert-word-documents-into-pdf-files/
' And asked for tweaking here
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564156/converting-multiple-word-documents-to-multiple-pdfs-at-the-same-time-using-vbscr
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Explicit
Dim Title
Title = "Doc2PDF to Convert Multiple .doc or .docx files to PDF files"

'We create a shortcut of this vbscript into SendTo Folder
Call Create_Shortcut(_
"Convert Word Docs to PDF",_
chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & chr(34),_
"%SystemRoot%\system32\msdt.exe,0",_
"Convert Multiple .doc or .docx files to PDF files")

On Error Resume Next
Call Doc2PDF()
If Err Then 
    Call ShowError()
    Wscript.Quit(1)
Else
    MsgBox "The Conversion of Doc(s) to PDF(s) files is Successfully Done !",VbInformation+vbSystemModal,Title
End If
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Create_Shortcut(ShortcutName,TargetPath,IconLocation,Description)
    Dim objShell,SendTo_Folder,objShortCut
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    SendTo_Folder = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(SendTo_Folder & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = TargetPath
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = IconLocation
    ObjShortCut.Description = Description
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Doc2PDF()
Dim fso,i,docPath,objWord,pdfPath,objDoc
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then Wscript.Quit
    For i= 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count -1
        docPath = WScript.Arguments(i)
        docPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(docPath)
        If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(docPath)) = LCase("doc") _
        Or LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(docPath)) = LCase("docx") Then
            Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            pdfPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(docPath) & "\" & _
            fso.GetBaseName(docpath) & ".pdf"
            objWord.Visible = False
            Set objDoc = objWord.documents.open(docPath)
            objDoc.saveas pdfPath,17
            objDoc.Close
            objWord.Quit
        Else
            MsgBox "You must send only files with those extensions "".doc"" or "".docx""",vbExclamation,Title
            Wscript.Quit(1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ShowError()
    Dim ErrLine
    ErrLine  = Get_Date_Time
    ErrLine  = ErrLine &  vbcrlf &_
    "Error " & err.number & " (0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & vbcrlf &_
    err.Description & vbCrlf &_
    "Source : " & err.Source
    MsgBox ErrLine,vbCritical,Title 
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Get_Date_Time()
    Get_Date_Time = LPad(Day(Now),2,"0") & "/" & LPad(Month(Now),2,"0") & "/" & Year(Now) &_
    vbTab & LPad(Hour(Now),2,"0") & ":" & LPad(Minute(Now),2,"0")  & ":" & LPad(Second(Now),2,"0")
End Function
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function LPad(s, l, c)
  Dim n : n = 0
  If l > Len(s) Then n = l - Len(s)
  LPad = String(n, c) & s
End Function
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```